# Using WCF http to communicate over a LAN

Tags: c#, wcf, http, c#-4.0, distributed-computing

Im trying to communicate with two pc's via an ethernet cable. I've gone into the settings and told it to use two specific ip addresses. Ive turned the firewalls off on both pc's and managed to ping from one pc to the other. When i try and use the following code, its not working though. Something about nothing listening at the specified address. Any ideas?

//SERVER

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFServer
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IStringReverser
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string ReverseString(string value);
  }

  public class StringReverser : IStringReverser
  {
    public string ReverseString(string value)
    {
      char[] retVal = value.ToCharArray();
      int idx = 0;
      for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        retVal[idx++] = value[i];

      return new string(retVal);
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
        typeof(StringReverser),
        new Uri[]{
          new Uri("http://192.168.10.10")
        }))
      {

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStringReverser),
          new BasicHttpBinding(),
          "Reverse");

        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is available. " +  
          "Press <ENTER> to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        host.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

//CLIENT

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace WCFClient
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IStringReverser
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string ReverseString(string value);
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ChannelFactory<IStringReverser> httpFactory =
         new ChannelFactory<IStringReverser>(
          new BasicHttpBinding(),
          new EndpointAddress(
            "http://192.168.10.9"));


      IStringReverser httpProxy =
        httpFactory.CreateChannel();

      while (true)
      {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("http: " + 
          httpProxy.ReverseString(str));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Address your service is listening to is `http://192.168.10.10/Reverse` (Uri you gave plus endpoint name you gave), you should connect your client to this endpoint instead of `http://192.168.10.9`.

Comment: Sorry im a little green when it comes to these things + i cant check right now as im not at my pc. So in the Client code, i need to specify the IP address of the other computer which is the Server. In the Server code, i need to put the same IP address as the computer actually running the code? How would i then allow the Server to Call the Client first or would the Client always have to call the Server first? Thanks very much for your help thus far.

Comment: Correct. "Reverse" is the name you gave to your endpoint in the Server: `host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStringReverser), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Reverse");`. Notice the last parameter. That's appended to your IP so you can have multiple endpoints per IP if you call AddServiceEndpoint multiple times.

Comment: Thanks very much for clearing that up. One thing im still a little fuzzy on. The Server is just listening at a specific port until the Client sends info to that specific port. How does the Server know which address to send the info back to? Is it possible for the Server to call the Client first. I read something about having to use wsDualHttpBinding. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Sending a response back to the client is handled automatically by the host, you don't need to keep track of where your request came from. You cannot call the client first... that would reverse the roles of client and server. You can have two servers if you like.

Comment: Do you have time to answer a couple questions in a chat room, please?